# access at the i-th element in json file from a call httprequest of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to access the i-th element rom $httprequest, but when I try to write this method to see if in the alert function appears  the element of the scope, in the window alert appears **" variable UNDEFINED"**, why?

Thanks in advance.

```
 angular.module('userListApp', [])
    .factory('userService', function ($http) {;
        var users = []; 
          return {
          users: users,
            load: function () {;
            $http
            .get('http://localhost:8080/users')
            .success(function (data) {;
               users.push.apply(users, data);
            });
          }
        };
    })
    .controller('UsersController', function ($scope, userService) {;
      $scope.users = userService.users;
      userService.load();
     userService.toString();;

       alert($scope.users[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userService.load` is asynchronous, so when you alert the response hasn't come back yet, and there is no `users[0]`. You could $watch users, or use `$q` in the load to resolve a promise. Something like this:

```
angular.module('userListApp', [])
.factory('userService', function ($http) {;
    var users = []; 
    return {
      users: users,
      load: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http
        .get('http://localhost:8080/users')
        .success(function(data) {
           users.push.apply(users, data);
           deferred.resolve();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
})
.controller('UsersController', function ($scope, userService) {;
  $scope.users = userService.users;
  userService.load().then(function() {
    alert($scope.users[0]);
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry but  than if i wanted to take one elemen from my call httprequest what would i write?i mean there isn't some function more chiper to extract the element from httprequest/json?

Comment: i've resolved....i could've just did `$scope.Object[k].NameColumnJsonFile` 
Thanks anyway. ^^

Answer (score -1):

Because `$http.get` is *asynchronous*, and returns a promise.
As usual, you could just do:

```
userService.load().then(function () {
    alert($scope.users[0]); // Here, the load function will be over.
});
```

Don't forget to read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), especially the part on promises.